# How to delete folder in GitLab using console

Tags: git, directory, gitlab

I have wrongly created a folder named `src` in my GitLab repository and now I want to delete this folder. I have tried several ways to delete it but I am able only to delete it locally but not in my GitLab repository. This folder is still there and i want to get rid off it. I have tried those commands

```
git rm -r src   
git commit -m "Remove  directory"   
git push -u origin master
```

but it still does not delete the folder in my GitLab repository.

I have also tried this :

```
git rm -r --cached src
```

and none of them seems to work for me .

Answer (score 4):

Git doesn't track directories, only their contents. But `git rm -r src` should have done it. Here's possible things to check.

Was the `git push` successful? If not, then the remote will not be updated.

Double check that `origin` is what you think it is with `git remote -v`.

Double check that you're looking at the right branch, `master`.

If you're talking about what Gitlab displays in a web browser, make a new clone of your repository and check if `src` is still there. If it isn't then it's probably an issue with their web display, possibly a caching issue.

If after you've done all that and are still flummoxed, contact Gitlab about it.

WRT `git rm --cached`, the `--cached` refers to the staging area (also called the cache, also called the index). It's where `git add` copies files to build up the next commit. It lives on your machine and has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked with gitlab web IDE. I just deleted a folder and committed it and also I renamed my project's folder name.

So I think we can do this with WEB IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete folder from your local system then **add all**, **commit**, then **push origin master**.

Comment: Simple and easy solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your branch

rm -rf -- foldername {Delete a folder}

rm filename {Delete a file}