# How to delete folder from gitlab

Tags: java, gitlab

i'm learning java and pushing on Gitlab. I have some projects there and now i need to delete one of them(not the whole branch, but folder with application). How can i properly do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete folder in GitLab using console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456295/how-to-delete-folder-in-gitlab-using-console)

Answer (score 2):

To delete files.
You can do it locally.

Delete the file you want and run
git add .

Notice the (dot) after git add above.
The dot means "you want to stage all changes for commit"

Then commit the changes, to commit run
 git commit -m "deleted unnecessary file"

Finally push to your repo using the command
git push origin branch_name_here
E.g git push origin master.

This way, the deleted file is gone